# Bootstrap scrollspy not working with HAML

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, haml, scrollspy

I am trying to implement `scrollspy` from the Bootstrap library. Currently tab that I manually activated stays active and nothing on the `nav` changes if I scroll or click. I have the following. Any ideas?

```
.row
  %ul{ :id => "navthingy", :class => "nav nav-tabs nav-stacked fixed span3" }
    %li.active
      %a.icon-user{ :href => '#profile'}
        Profile
    %li
      %a.icon-lightbulb{ :href => '#ideas'}
        Ideas
    %li
      %a.icon-arrow-right{ :href => '#followings'}
        Followings
    %li
      %a.icon-group{ :href => '#teams'}
        Teams
  .span3
  .span9{ :data => { :spy => "scroll", :target => "#navthingy" } }
    .header-banner
      %a.anchor{ :id => 'profile'}
      %h2
        = @user.name
        %small
          = pluralize(@user.ideas.count, "Idea")
          = pluralize(@user.followings.count, "Following")
          = @user.created_at.strftime("Joined %B %Y")
    .user-info
      %p
        %strong= @user.occupation
      %p= @user.info

    .header-banner.spaced
      %a.anchor{ :id => 'ideas'}
      %h2
        Ideas
        %small
          = "Suggested #{pluralize(@user.ideas.count, 'idea')}"    
    = render partial: 'ideas/ideas', locals: { ideas: @user.ideas }

    .header-banner.spaced
      %a.anchor{ :id => 'followings'}
      %h2
        Following
        %small
          = "Following #{pluralize(@user.following_ideas.count, 'idea')}"
    = render partial: 'ideas/ideas', locals: { ideas: @user.following_ideas }

    .header-banner.spaced
      %a.anchor{ :id => 'teams'}
      %h2
        Teams
        %small
          = "Member on #{pluralize(@user.accepted_teams.count, 'team')}"
    = render partial: 'ideas/ideas', locals: { ideas: @user.accepted_teams.map { |x| x.idea } }

:javascript
  $(document).ready(function() {
      equalHeight($(".thumbnail-top"));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve something [like here](http://appizy.com/examples/bs-onepage/). You can use Appizy. Just have to put your content into a spreadsheet and then the software creates a nice one-page web with a scrollspy in it.

There is a tutorial [video here as well](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XyyzT5rxI5U).

Hope that helps you! Nicolas